# Python-Turtle-Effectively recreating buttons

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm doing an assignment using the turtle module, in which I'm creating a text based game. I'm fairly new to code in general and python and I'd like to simulate buttons to be pressed using the mouse. From looking at other threads, I'm fairly sure it is possible by moving the turtle to the mouseclick and then executing an action dependent on whether or not the python is within a designated area, which will be illustrated visually as the button. Because I'm inexperienced, I am unsure about how to specify the coordinates and check whether or not the turtle is within them.

Here is what I started with:

```
from turtle import *
import turtle as t
from time import sleep
import time as time

pen= Turtle()
bt=pen.clone()
bt.pu()
bt.setpos(-200,-200)
menu=0

pen.pu()
pen.setpos(0,50)
pen.write("1.Option1",align="center",font=("Chiller",40))
time.sleep(0.5)

pen.setpos(0,-30)
pen.write("2.Option2",align="center",font=("Chiller",40))
time.sleep(0.5)

pen.setpos(0,-110)
pen.write("3.Option3",align="center",font=("Chiller",40))
menu=1

while menu==1:
    screen= Screen()
    screen.onscreenclick(bt.goto)
    bt.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
while menu==1:
    if bt.xcor>(-200) and bt.xcor<(200):
        if bt.ycor>(20) and bt.ycor<(80):
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("option 1")
        elif bt.ycor>(-60) and bt.ycor<(0):
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("option 2")
        elif bt.ycor>(-140) and bt.ycor<(-80):
            pen.clear()
            pen.write("option 3")
```

As I said, idiot language would be appreciated; can someone tell me why this doesn't work and possibly offer a solution. Also, I'm not entirely sure what the "screen=Screen()" bit does, I just found it in a different thread and implemented it...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: whats not working? and it looks like your indentation is off ...

Comment: Have you met PyGame yet?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.

In your question, please be specific about what is not working, your output, your desired output and the errors (if any) that you may be getting.

Comment: @JoranBeasley When it is run, and the mouse is clicked within the one of the three 'button' areas, it should display the corresponding text but it does not. Where is my indentation off?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, I'm unaware of that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.  (Whether it should be done is another question.)  Below is demonstration code that changes the text at the bottom of the screen when you click one of the three options:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONTSIZE = 40
FONT = ("Ariel", FONTSIZE, "normal")

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.penup()

turtle.setpos(0, FONTSIZE*2 - FONTSIZE/2)
turtle.write("1.Option1", align="center", font=FONT)

turtle.setpos(0, -FONTSIZE/2)
turtle.write("2.Option2", align="center", font=FONT)

turtle.setpos(0, -FONTSIZE*2 - FONTSIZE/2)
turtle.write("3.Option3", align="center", font=FONT)

turtle.setpos(-200, -200)
turtle.write("Select an Option", font=FONT)

def onclick_handler(x, y):
    if -100 < x < 100:
        if FONTSIZE < y < FONTSIZE*3:
            turtle.undo()
            turtle.write("Option 1", font=FONT)
        elif -FONTSIZE < y < FONTSIZE:
            turtle.undo()
            turtle.write("Option 2", font=FONT)
        elif -FONTSIZE*3 < y < -FONTSIZE:
            turtle.undo()
            turtle.write("Option 3", font=FONT)

screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(onclick_handler)
screen.mainloop()
```

Your original code had an infinite loop in it which complicated matters -- you shouldn't have infinite loops in turtle programs.  Rather than have your click handler move the turtle and then have the infinite loop detect where the turtle is menu-wise, you can simply have your click handler determine where the click was menu-wise and avoid some complexity.

Beyond that, hardcoding numbers is always troublesome and you should always try to avoid them.  Calculate what you can, document with a constant variable what you can't.